# Не работает условие if в xsl шаблоне

Tags: xslt, шаблонизаторы

Есть XSL шаблон.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
    <xsl:template match="udata">
        <div class="product-info">
            <div class="product-info-title">
                <span>Название: </span>
                <h4><a href="{@link}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="node()"/></a></h4>
                <xsl:value-of select="page/name" />
            </div>
            <div class="product-info-price">
                <span>Цена: </span>
                <xsl:value-of select="//property[@name = 'price']/value" />
            </div>
            <div class="product-info-price"></div>
        </div>


    <xsl:if test="bk &lt; bn">
      <span>Название вариант 1</span>
    </xsl:if>



    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Условие `<xsl:if test="bk &lt; bn">` не работает.

Переменные из PHP функции передаю так.

```
$block_arr['attribute:link'] = 'http://yandex.ru';
$block_arr['node:name'] = 'Text';
$block_arr['attribute:bn'] = 1;
$block_arr['attribute:bk'] = 3;
return def_module::parseTemplate($template_block, $block_arr);
```

Вот это в шаблон нормально подставляется:

```
$block_arr['attribute:link'] = 'http://yandex.ru';
$block_arr['node:name'] = 'Text';
```

Помогите понять в чем проблема?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поскольку `bn` и `bk` — атрибуты, перед их именами нужно использовать`@`:

```
<xsl:if test="@bk &lt; @bn">
```

Comment: спасибо. я пробовал так же, но у меня почему то не срабатывало. Сейчас работает.